# RegEx Max and Min length characters for a Text Box

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I use Asp.net and C#.

I need force the User to add in a TextBox Control only between 4 and 128 characters text.

I would like to use a ValidationExpression Property for a Validation Control.

Could you point me out a correct **Regular Expression?**

Notes: I'm using this code right now, but it seems not working properly if there are double spaces or break line in the TextBox

```
ValidationExpression="^.{4,128}$"
```

Thanks for your time on this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression is correct. Just use the `Singleline` modifier, to make the dot also match newline characters.

```
RegexOptions.Singleline
```

Or as inline modifier

```
"^(?s)(.){4,128}$"
```

[RegexOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)
[Regular Expression Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx)

Comment: thanks stema, sorry to make it clear shall I use this version or ^(.|\n|\r){4,128}$ you posted to me as a comment? What is the difference among the two? once again many thanks

Comment: I would prefer the version in my answer. The difference is that the Singleline modifier includes `\r\n` into `.` where in the other version you do this work by yourself by writing them down explicitly. I think in your simple case its a matter of taste, but when you have a larger expression the modifier is better, because you can't forget to write down the newlines at some place.

Answer (score 2):

> The full stop or period character (.) is known as dot. It is a wildcard that will match any character except a new line (\n).

Reference: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx

---

Try this instead:

```
ValidationExpression = "^(.|\n|\t){4,128}$"
```

I added tabs (`\t`) as well.

Tell me if it worked or not!

Comment: dot should Matches any single character except line break characters \r and \n. why have you use \r instead? thanks for your time on this

Comment: Well, in my quote only `\n` was mentioned. You could add it just to be safe `(.|\n|\r|\t){4,128}$`. However, this could mean that both `\r` as `\n` are considered to be a character each. You could try this instead: `(.|(\n|\r|\r\n|\n\r)|\t){4,128}$`. Might look whacky but I guess it'll do the job!

Comment: The dot matches anything, but newline characters. No need to add `\t` to your expression. And it would be enough to have `^(.|\n|\r){4,128}$` no need for the permutations of `\n` and `\r` in your alternation, but of course every one is counted as own character.

Comment: Thats why I added all possibilities of new lines, to make sure they're counted as one character instead of two. Usually I wouldn't do this, but for the sake of his project this is the best method. You're probably right about the tabs though.

Answer (score 0):

try this `ValidationExpression = ^(\w*)(\s*)(.*){4,128}$"` it will cover periods and spaces as well.

Comment: you may need to add \t.. i don't think that tabs are considered as several spaces

Comment: `\s` covers also tab. But your expression accepts only at first any amount of `\w` characters then any amount of `\s` characters then any amount of any character except newline and on this last part you put the `{4,128}` quantifier (You accept 4  to 128 times any amount of any character?). This is absolutely not doing what the OP wants.

Comment: thanks ... what is the difference from your version and ^(.|\n|\r){4,128}$ from stema?