# How to escape a RegEx that generates an error of “unexpected quantifier"on IE?

Tags: asp.net, regex, internet-explorer

I use asp.net and C#. I have  TextBox with an Validation Control with  RegEx.

I use this code as validation.

```
ValidationExpression="^(?s)(.){4,128}$"
```

But only in IE9 I receive an error: `unexpected quantifier`  from the javascript section.

Probably I have to **escape** my RegEx but I do not have any idea how to do it and what to escape.

Could you help me with a sample of code? Thanks

Comment: The problem is the `(?s)`. What is that capture group intended to match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it like this instead :

```
 ^([\s\S]){4,128}$
```

I suspect that (?s) is the cause of the error.

Comment: thanks for your code, but why have you added the \S ? afaik \S is the negative version of \s not?

Comment: Yes. That makes the character class match literally everything, exactly the same effect as (?s). for the .

Comment: I tried your code and my error disappear, could you confirm taht you escaped version is exactly the same as mine previously posted??? here another linked post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133066/regex-max-and-min-length-characters-for-a-text-box

Comment: @GibboK Yes I hereby confirm that this expression is exactly the same as the one in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Three problems: (1) JavaScript doesn't support inline modifiers like `(?s)`, (2) there's no other way to pass modifiers in an ASP validator, and (3) neither of those facts matters, because JavaScript doesn't support single-line mode.  Most people use `[\s\S]` to match anything-including-newlines in JavaScript regexes.

**EDIT:** Here's how it would look in your case:

```
ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{4,128}$"
```

`[\s\S]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any whitespace character (`\s`) or any character that's *not* a whitespace character--in other words, any character.  The dot (`.`) metacharacter matches any character except a newline.  Most regex flavors (like .NET's) support a "Singleline" or "DOTALL" mode that makes the dot match newlines, too, but not JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for your answer I do not know anything about JS a very very little about RegEx. Could you please post your code so I can test it and approve the answer?

Comment: Thanks Alan.. I would accept even you answer but I unfortunately I can only accept one. I gave you an up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't understand `(?s)` afaik, instead you can replace `.` with `[^]` or `[\s\S]`.

Eg: `^[^]{4,128}$`

Comment: Yes, that's the point of replacing the `.` with what I said, to make it work as if `(?s)` was used.